# Missed MOK password entry while booting

Tags: boot, drivers, wireless, 21.04

I am new to MOK so please forgive mistakes. I got a new laptop and installed 21.04. The Wifi driver was not working. With help from someone on the internet, I located the Debian package for the Realtek Wifi card and installed it. It said that if I enable secure boot, Wifi will not work. And that is how it is now. I am using ethernet for the internet.

During last day's update, there came some prompt that my 3rd party drivers will work even though the secure boot is enabled if I use a particular password. I entered the password and I was prompted with 3 options while rebooting after the update.

I was totally new to MOK and I clicked " Continue with Boot " something like that. It seems that MOK option is missed and I do not have WiFi enabled now.

My question is, 1. Can I get WiFi working again if I somehow manage to enter the MOK password. 2. Is it safe to use this MOK option 3. How can I get the MOK prompt again so that I will not have driver issues due to the secure boot and get Wifi back.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any reason to keep Secure Boot enabled? Disabling it solves ALL your problems.

Comment: Protects us from rootkit like threats, right ?

Comment: No, not really. It may make some sense for Windows (Windows 11 is rumored to require it, hence my question) but for everything else is mostly a pain in the...

Comment: I have Windows 10 as dual boot

Comment: Windows 10 works perfectly fine without Secure Boot.

Comment: Thanks. So I can disable secure boot and still be safe ?

Comment: You (your behavior) are the measure of safety.